# Como imprimir un documento especifico en C#

Tags: c#

Necesito hacer un codigo para enviar directamente el archivo 1.pdf a la impresora pero envía el documento en blanco, alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?

```
string FileName = @"C:\1.pdf";

PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
pdoc.DocumentName = FileName;
pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "RICOH MP C4504";
pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = FileName;
pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;    
pdoc.Print();
```

Comment: Debes asegurar el nombre de la impresora de otra forma no podràs imprimir

Answer (score 1):

El problema inicialmente es que tratas de imprimir a un archivo en lugar de a un puerto usando [PrintToFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printtofile?view=windowsdesktop-5.0), comenta las lineas que indico:

```
string FileName = @"C:\1.pdf";

PrintDocument pdoc = new PrintDocument();
pdoc.DocumentName = FileName;
pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "RICOH MP C4504";
//pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = FileName;
//pdoc.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;    
pdoc.Print();
```